# How to find the first item that occurs within a group of dates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a listing of operating rooms that are doing surgery each day... OR 1, OR 2 and OR 3.

For January 3, we did 4 cases. I want to find the first occurrence of "OR 1" that appears for January 3. Likewise, I want to find the first occurrence of "OR 2" and "OR 3" for that day.

THEN...

Move on to January 4, and identify the same thing... the first occurrence of "OR 1", "OR 2" then "OR 3".

Then move on to repeat this for each date that I have in the list. I want to identify these first occurrences with the word "Yes" next to it. Here is an example...

[image]

**The logic should be:** For each date, what is the first occurrence of each OR room?

Any guidance on how to build the logic?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Use `COUNTIFS()`. It's a re-occuring type of question. It won't be too hard to find material here on SO.

Comment: If they are in date order, then just count back...

Comment: As @JvdV Sir has mentioned, its a re-occuring type of question hence not posting it as an answer, !, So If I assume the database starts from A1 then apply anyone of these formulas, `=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A1,$B$1:B1,B1)=1,"YES","")` or `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:A1=A1)*($B$1:B1=B1))=1,"YES","")` that should give you the desired output for the first occurrence !